# Add Maven generated site to generated package

Tags: maven-2, jar, maven-plugin

In order to deliver an all-in-one Jar for our project, we are wondering if it is possible to include the project's generated site (generated via the site plugin) into the generated project's package?
The idea behind this is very simple, we have a project named "sample" that demonstrates the usage of our API and we want to give the user documentation on the API and its usage in a single bundle.
Is it possible using Maven to create such a Jar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`site:jar`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/jar-mojo.html) and then the assembly plugin to create a bundle of everthing should be possible.

Comment: Yep this could be an interesting solution.
I am going to try it.

Comment: I am looking to do similar thing, did this work for you?  Could you post some more details please.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting here to document a solution for building a war file with the maven generated site included with the recent Maven 3. I have wrapped the required build plugins into a profile which is activated by Hudson setting the BUILD_NUMBER system property. In addition to adding the site directory to the war, this configuration generates a -javadoc.jar artifact (the separate maven-javadoc-plugin with the attach-javadocs execution is responsible for that, and you can remove it if not required).

```
<profiles>
    <!-- We want the javadoc jar and the site within the war only when building on Hudson -->
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>BUILD_NUMBER</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0-beta-3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            </plugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions> 
                        <execution> 
                            <id>attach-site</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals> 
                        </execution> 
                    </executions> 
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/site</directory>
                                <targetPath>doc</targetPath>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is the same profile, but for Maven2. This is useful if you have a hudson project configuration relying on the maven2 hudson plugin.

```
<profiles>
    <!-- We want the javadoc jar and the site within the war only when building on Hudson -->
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>BUILD_NUMBER</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/site</directory>
                                <targetPath>doc</targetPath>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions> 
                        <execution> 
                            <id>attach-site</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals> 
                        </execution> 
                    </executions> 
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: any way to convert it to a war file? all it really needs is a generic web.xml file. that would make it deployable to a web app container

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to configure maven-site-plugin to generate site in a phase happening before the package (e.g. prepare-package) and then include the generated site into the webapp configuring maven-war-plugin properly.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>site</goal>
                <goal>stage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/target/staging</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[Here](https://github.com/sixro/try-site-in-webapp) you can find a sample project using this configuration.
[Here](https://trysiteinwebapp.herokuapp.com/) a live demo.