# Maven: Package files generated during site lifecycle using Assembly plugin

Tags: xml, maven, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm attempting to package some files that get generated during the `site life-cycle` of a maven project so that I can automatically share these resources with other projects that use them.

I have successfully used the maven assembly plugin to package files that already exist in the project(under `/src/main/...`), however when I try to package files in the `/target/site/` path into a zip it always ends up being empty.

The `POM.xml` looks something like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make shared resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/resources.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The assembly descriptor

```
<assembly>
  <id>resources</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/site/</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I have attempted changing the phase to `<phase>post-site</phase>` but I have the feeling the plugin only executes on the default life-cycle.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please see [Add Maven generated site to generated package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327843/add-maven-generated-site-to-generated-package).

Comment: How did you call maven?

Answer (score 0):

On important thing which comes into my mind is: If you have files which needed as a dependency for other project you have to generate them during the usual life-cycle and not during the **site** life cyclce.